# Why width of container smaller on full hd laptop?

Tags: html, css, hidpi

I have a html template for Joomla SPPB with:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />`

It have container:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .ph {
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
}
```

On my 24" (1920x1200) screen it's ok. But on 15" (1920x1200) laptop, it visibly smaller, than 1140 px. When I make a screenshot and measure it in Photoshop, it is near 950px.

I understand that on a smaller screen it will be smaller, but why I have CSS px disproportion?

Comment: "Visibly smaller" can be deceiving on different DPI screens. Did you test with developer tools whether the actual pixel values are less than you expect?

Comment: Is your browser on 15" laptop on the correct zoom level? Try to press `Ctrl/Cmd + 0` if not

Comment: Bram, I trying change DPI in Chrome Dev Tools, but nothing change.
Hao Wu, zoom is 100%.

Comment: It's maybe because of the zoom which you have set in the windows display setting. Check there, your 24" screen would have 125% and laptop might be on 100%. Check once